# how to send hidden field value to the controller formcollection data?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am getting data using `var data = new FormData($('form').get(0));` in jquery.
and sending 'data' object to the controller using ajax. I have one hidden field in the form. How to append that hidden field or hidden field value to the 'data' object?

On inspect element hidden field has `disabled="disabled"` attribute. how to append 
particulate hidden field value to form data using jquery?

Comment: You give it a id to hidden field, then access it like..$('id'),  Alka mam put the code as well so can be corrected  :)

Comment: Can you provide your razor/aspx markup? What is the reason for the hidden field to be disabled? If you remove that attribute before calling the ajax it will be send along with the form if it is in it: $( "#hidden-Input-id" ).removeAttr('disabled'); If you don't want to remove it you can use a concatenation of both the form and hidden input .serialize() results to be sent to server.

Comment: Use its name like `$('input[name="inputname"]')` to get its value in jquery and append i to formData

Comment: I have set `$( "#hidden-Input-id" ).removeAttr('disabled'); ` before the ajax calling and its working. thanks @SamuilPetrov

Comment: Disabled fields aren't included.  Hidden fields are.  Disabled fields stop the user changing them, hidden fields can't be changed by the user (as they're hidden....) so there shouldn't be a reason to disable a hidden field at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the hidden field value using   **`$("#HiddenFieldID").val()`**.

But if the hidden field is placed inside the form tag. The form data will contains that hidden field value.

**The following code demonstrate how to get the value from form data.**

```js
 $("#FrmSample").submit( function(eventObj) {
      eventObj.preventDefault();
  $("#result").html(new FormData(this));
    var inputs =  $("#FrmSample").serializeArray();
    $.each(inputs, function (i, inputj) {
       console.log(inputj.value);
    });
    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="FrmSample" action="#">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="hidden" id="HiddenControl" name="HiddenControl"  value="SampleValue">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
  
</body>
</html>
```

***Or if you want to append particular form field value you can use the code bellow.***

```
$("#FrmSample").submit( function(eventObj) {
      $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
          .attr('name', "something")
          .attr('value', "something")
          .appendTo('#form');
      return true;
  });
```